# Which excel formula use following data

Tags: excel

I have data in sheet one and I want to crate summery in second sheet example

***Sheet1***

```
Column 1                   column 2
Bank statement             Complite
Bank Gurantee              process
BG Report                  complite
Cash Transaction           Future
old CAsh transaction       Process
FD Transaction             Complite
```

***Sheet2***

```
Complite            Process           Future
Bank Statement     Bank Gurantee      Cash Transaction
BG Report          Old Cash Transa.   
FD Transaction
```

Which formula should I use?

Answer (score 0):

With `Excel365` you can use `FILTER` function.

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7=D$1)
```

If you are not in `Excel365` then use below formula then drag down and across as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$6)/($B$2:$B$7=D$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: You have to adjust formula to see result in `Sheet2`.